# PS Remote session without passing credentials

Tags: powershell, session, kerberos, powershell-remoting

I want to start a `New-PSSession` without having to pass credentials in a script. I know you can get the password from a file or have it hardcoded in the script and then convert it to a secure string to start the session. However, I want to start the session using the current user's credentials.

The machine I am trying to remote to is in the same domain.

I tried:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName machineInDomain
```

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server failed with the
>   following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The
>   following error occured while using Kerberos authentication: The
>   network path was not found.  Possible causes are:
>   -The user name or
>   password specified are invalid.
>   -Kerberos is used when no
>   authentication method and no user name are specified.
>   -Kerberos
>   accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
>   -The Service
>   Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not
>   exist.   -The client and remote computers are in different domains and
>   there is no trust between the two domains.  After checking for the
>   above issues, try the following:
>   -Check the Event Viewer for events
>   related to authentication.
>   -Change the authentication method; add
>   the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration
>   setting or us e HTTPS transport.  Note that computers in the
>   TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>   -For more information
>   about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help
>   config. For more information,  see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic.
>
> At line:1 char:16
>   + Enter-PSSession <<<<  -ComputerName machineInDomain
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (machineInDomain:String) [Enter-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

Kerberos should pass the current user's credentials with trust if in the same domain.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteHost -Authentication Kerberos
```

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message
>   : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: The computer
>   $RemoteHost is unknown to Kerberos. Verify that the computer exists on the network, that the name
>   provided is spelled correctly, and that the Kerberos configuration for accessing the computer is correct. The most
>   common Kerberos configuration issue is that an SPN with the format HTTP/$RemoteHost is not
>   configured for the target. If Kerberos is not required, specify the Negotiate authentication mechanism and resubmit
>   the operation. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> ```
> At line:1 char:1
> + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $RemoteHost -Authentication Ke ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: ($RemoteHost) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
> ```

It seems to be a domain problem.

Comment: New-PSSession uses the current user's credentials by default. I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: Are these domain joined PCs?  If they are domain joined then as @EBGreen says, the current creds are used by default.  Or are you trying this from a workgroup?

Comment: I am in a domain, current credentials are not used even if in domain!

Comment: i dont know if this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782312(v=ws.10).aspx
is outdated